# Android photo upload cutting off image?

Tags: android, sql, image, asp.net-mvc-5, camera

I'm working on an app that allows users to upload photos from their smart phones via an `HTML` input element. Basic flow is they click the input element, choose camera, take picture, then it is displayed in a preview window. When they submit the form, the image is `scaled down to 1200x900` and the `base64 dataURL` of the resized image is saved in to a `SQL` database so I can directly use it as the src for `<img>` on a details page.

**Razor/Html:**

```
Attach Image:
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" onchange="picChange(event)" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:5px;"/>
<span id="fileSizeinfo"></span>
<img id="capturedPhoto" src="~/Content/Images/cameraglyph_1x.png" style="border-radius:5px;background-color:darkgray;border:solid;display:block;margin:auto;width:100%;" />

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Photo, new {  @hidden="hidden", id="photoData"})
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function picChange(evt) {
var fileInput = evt.target.files;
if (fileInput.length > 0) {
    var photoImg = document.getElementById("capturedPhoto");
    var photoData = document.getElementById("photoData");
    var filesizeSpan = document.getElementById("fileSizeinfo");

    var photo = evt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    filesizeSpan.textContent = Math.round(photo.size * 0.000001) + 'Mb(s) - ' + Math.round(photo.size * 0.001) + 'kbs';

    reader.onload = function (theFile) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {

            var aspectRatio = img.width / img.height;
            var desiredWidth = 1200;
            var desiredHeight = desiredWidth / aspectRatio;

            var photoCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            photoCanvas.width = desiredWidth;
            photoCanvas.height = desiredHeight;

            var ctx = photoCanvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, desiredWidth, desiredHeight);

            var imageData = photoCanvas.toDataURL();
            photoImg.src = imageData;
            photoData.value = imageData; 
        }
        img.src = theFile.target.result;
    }
    var photoSrc = reader.readAsDataURL(photo);
}
}
```

When I click on the element on the phone, I get the correct camera/gallery dialog to select a picture from:
[image]

If I select camera, and then save the image it correctly displays in the preview window. The preview is an img element that's src is set to the dataURL of the downscaled picture that was just taken.
[image]

Once submitted, if I look at a details page, all of my camera images look like this:
[image]

They are always cut off abruptly, though it is correctly resized to `1200x900`. I thought maybe the dataURL was too long, so I uploaded an 11Mb picture using my desktop, and it resized and displayed properly so it definitely has something to do with using a phone. Decreasing the resolution of the camera fixes the issue, but I need my source images as high-res as possible before down-scaling them(precision industrial work).

Camera photos are typically around `3Mb` upon uploading. The strange thing is that they appear correctly in the preview window, which uses the same dataURL string that is saved to the database!

Tested on:

```
Android KitKat 4.4.2
Android Web Browser & Chrome Mobile
```

Comment: Hard to figure our your problem. If you only tested with default web browser, I recommend you to test other browsers including Chrome mobile, Firefox. Moreover, other Android phones with different OS version required to be tested. in example, 4.1.2 (Jellybean), 4.4 (Kitkat), or Lollipop (5.0).

Comment: I tested with android default browser, as well as chrome mobile. KitKat 4.4.2. I should have added this in the question.

Comment: I think your problem is laid in html not in camera doing because you said same url shows properly in preview right?

Comment: You are correct. On the details page, the uploaded image is displayed using FancyBox. However, uploading an extremely large image (11mb) from my desktop did not yield the same cut-off image, it worked perfectly. The preview window uses the same dataURL to display the image as what is uploaded to the database.

Comment: what about captured image of decreased resolution in file size? is this problem only occurred around 3Mb? how about 1,2,5Mb?

Comment: The problem resolves if I decrease the camera resolution to around 2MP, however I want to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: what's wrong with that specific range of file size. quizzy...

Comment: Because it is the difference between 2.5MP and 10MP. I need high resolution. Decreasing the resolution reduces the amount of image 'cut' out, but the entire image isn't visible until around 2.5MP, or less than 1MB. I want to know what is causing this, I already know the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer was an issue with the Chrome web browser. On android there must be some kind of character limit on an HTML TextBox, where as IE11 on a PC doesn't have a limit. I simply switched the field that submits the URI to a TextArea field and the problem went away, no other changes were necessary.